# How to select the iOS device to emulate from a Netbeans Cordova project?

Tags: ios, cordova, netbeans, ios-simulator

I am developing a Cordova application in Netbeans on my Mac. I select the iOS Emulator as the environment to run the project. Every time I run it, it opens in the iPhone 4S emulator. Is there a way to select the iOS device to emulate? I want to try the different sized iPhones and iPads.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this inside the emulator, in menu, `Hardware > Device > iOS Version`

Comment: Thanks but the application is no longer there when I try that

Comment: Run cordova emulate ios again